# FlowControl in ActionListener method in Java When JButton Clicked

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, actionevent

Please someone explain me the  control flow of ActionListener ,  for example we implemented t in our class registered  with a component and   did  override

```
 actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

now i am confused about ,  when we click the registered button  `what is the role of  (this)`  in   `addActionListener (this);`

Comment: See also [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html).

Answer (score 1):

`addActionListener (this)` indicates current class implements `ActionListener` interface and provides the implementation of `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`

**Example:**

```
public class SampleListener implements ActionListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Click me");
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: The class that is interested in processing an action event implements this interface, "and the object created with that class is registered with a component"   this  is object for whole class ? please can you give me  one example to explain how  (this) is object for whole class?

Comment: btn1.addActionListener(this);  so here (this) is object for my whole class? and   anywhere in my code  i can do  this .mymethod ();    is it like  that?

Comment: `this` means _current object_ not class.